# Identity and Access Manager not displaying "Use the Windows Azure Access Control Service" on Existing Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, acs

I have an existing Web Site hosted on Azure that works with Azure Cloud services. I am now trying to integrate it with ACS for Identity Management. When attempting to configure through the Identity and Access Manager, I only have 2 options:

- Use the Local Development STS to test your application
- Use a business identity provider (e.g. Windows Azure Active Directory, ADFSv2)

However, I need the 3rd option that is typically available: "Use the Windows Azure Access Control Service". I've created new web sites in the exact same format, and have that option. But for some reason with this existing one it does not show up.

Is there anything in particular in my configuration settings that might not be allowing this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you created any identity provider?
Please check the following article to get more detail :

http://blog.tomasjansson.com/configuring-windows-azure-active-directory-access-control

Comment: Yes I created an identity provider and am able to test out the namespace identity provider with other test applications with the sample applications available on msdn. Unfortunately I believe that the issue might be that this application is using some older frameworks, so I am attempting to do it other ways.